# doctrine association mapping and arrayCollection persist error

Tags: php, mysql, database, doctrine-orm

consider the following issue:
I have a *many-to-one* association between `Article` and `Author`.

```
class Author{
  /**
   * ...
   *@var ArrayCollection_of_Article
   */
   public $articles;
}

class Article{
   /**
   * ...
   *@var Author
   */
   public $author;
}
```

Making a new `Article` I have two types of code:
**1st one:**

```
$author = ORM::Find("Author",12); // fetch an Author with ID=12
$art = new Article();
$art->author=$author;
$author->articles->add($art);
ORM::Persist($art); // persist it to write to database
```

**2nd one:** (omit the line 4)

```
$author = ORM::Find("Author",12); // fetch an Author with ID=12
$art = new Article();
$art->author=$author;
ORM::Persist($art); // persist it to write to database
```

Which one is correct?
The first one works correctly. But the second one cause an error such the error below sometimes:

```
A new entity was found through a relationship that was not configured to cascade persist operations
```

I want to know whether the second one is possible or it will **always** cause a sql error.
Thanks...

Comment: Did the second cause any errors? Which one in case?

Comment: the second one cause error **sometimes**

Comment: Depending on the weather? Please post the whole orm annotations / configuration file, with the message error too [is it a PDO/Mysql error or a PHP error btw?].

Comment: @DariushJafari Which of those two entities are the `owning-side` ? Have you properly set the `cascade: [ persist ]` ?

Answer (score 0):

You must access to the relations using getters and setters, this is because Doctrine build a Proxy class extending from your Entity class and override your getters for provide lazy loading.